# Broken laptop screen in win7 installation

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-installation, lenovo-laptop

broken laptop screen in middle of win7 installation, will not boot straight to external monitor.
How can I restore? Or install?

Lenovo g560

Comment: This question will need to be clarified.  What do you mean that the screen is broken?  Physically cracked/broken?  Or some software issues that's keeping video from being displayed on the screen?  Can you access the BIOS?  Please explain what you've tried and what happened when you tried in detail.

Comment: The laptop fell during win7 installation, now there are only stripes showing on the screen. I tried plugin vga monitor and tried to reinstall win7 but its only shown on the laptops LCD. Any use in know shortcuts (Fn f123.. 123 windows +P) failed to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stripes you describe being on screen could be a number of things:

1. The LCD Panel of the screen could be damaged
2. The connector for the LCD panel to the laptop's internal video card has come loose and needs to be reseated
3. The laptop's internal video card has become damaged.

Typically, one would press the `Fn` key and the key with the monitor icon in it to switch to the external monitor. If you are unable to do this, I would believe that the internal laptop video card is damaged. As with any piece of electronics falling to the ground, it is possible that more than one component was damaged in the fall (like the keyboard or motherboard), so it is difficult to propose a fix without knowing exactly which component it damaged.